# How to show Cmd+<number> to the **tab** title?

Tags: macos, terminal

[image]

I was watching a video and this guy managed to add Cmd+number to the tabs title *- instead of the window title that only shows the current selected tab -* how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In term2, the default is to show the command and number. See image below.

[image]